# how to log information when a file is executed

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I want to log information when a file is executed and hopefully tail that information. What is the best way to log for example a timestamp and ip address when a file is being executed via ssh terminal as opposed to writing a php script within the file to log it in text file or db.

Answer (score 1):

There is the *audit* system, in Linux. First download and install the *auditd* package, make sure the auditd daemon has started, then you can configure the operations to carry out by means of the *auditctl* command, which comes with the *auditd* package. A typical command would be

```
auditctl -a exit,always -w /path/to/file
```

The *-a exit,always* option instructs the kernel to examine, at the end 
(on *exit* ) of every syscal ( *always* ) whether a modification of any sort to the file in question has taken place. The audit events are then recorded in */var/log/audit/audit.log* (at least for the distros I use, YMMV).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i will let you know how I go with auditd.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your purpose, but it is easy enough to create a wrapper script - for example in BASH to log the execution time.

You may have difficulty getting the IP address as once the user is logged in BASH does not keep a record of the IP address.  You might be able to get this - after a fashion - by parsing "who" and getting the IP address associated with the user, but that makes possibly incorrect assumptions about the user.

You could also set up a special user or shell which logs what a user is doing and limits them. Alternatively you might be able to modify the "prompt" script ($PS1 variable) to log when commands are issued.

Lastly, depending on your distro (and pain tolerance) you might be able to use SELinux or Apparmour to log when certain files are executed.